# Resetting Chosen JQuery dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

So I have multiple dropdowns which are dependent on each other. When the button is clicked, it will do something if each dropdown has a value to it and it will also clear out the options and regenerate the options for chosen-province. If the user misses a dropdown, it will prompt them the message until all the options are selected. However, after the dropdowns are reset, the dialog box will appear again even if i have selected all the options and if i miss one dropdown, the dialog box will appear multiple times.

The code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/Charan98/y61kns0d/3/

```
$('.chosen-region').empty()
$('.chosen-region').trigger("chosen:updated");
$('.chosen-sitestat').empty()
$('.chosen-sitestat').trigger("chosen:updated");
$('.chosen-province').empty()
$('.chosen-province').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: Could you share a reproduction instead of a snippet ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa due to confidentially, i cannot share as my code uses private data and links

Comment: @Bob You should always create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This way we can debug your code and explain what is going wrong. Sensitive data can be replaced my meaningless data.

Comment: We don't need your links and data to help you fix your code. Add some dummy text and links ?

Comment: @freedomn-m i removed the .trigger("chosen:updated") but I'm still encountering the same issue

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I did

Comment: Please see the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Charan98/y61kns0d/3/

Comment: You've nested your reset button inside change - so a) it can't be used until province is changed and b) will add *multiple* event handlers each time province is changed (unless I'm missing something else in your code) - you can see this by changing province a few times, then clicking reset - you get multiple alerts.   Don't nest event handlers for existing elements.

Comment: @freedomn-m so should i add a separate reset button?

Comment: No, not a separate reset *button* - move the reset button event handler out of the select change event handler.  This is likely what's causing your "*the dialog box will appear multiple times"*